# How to make circle image in nav responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a chat nav bar with divs for different users in which there is a photo of the user. I want the photo to be a circle. I am doing it with padding-bottom and width, but the problem comes when the width:height ratio of the screen gets bigger the circle gets larger than the nav , because of the padding-bottom being calculated by the width. What is best approach to make this responsive for all screens?https://jsfiddle.net/n386ejzf/

```css
    html{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .chats{
        height: 20%;
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
    }
    .chat{
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
      background: yellow;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .img{
      width: 10%;
      padding-bottom: 10%;
      background: blue;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="chats">
        <div class="chat">
            <div class="img">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: I'd go for `@media` route, to put the screensize into account when set the image size

Comment: The only way I can get the circle outside the div is when the height is **~300px** and width is **>1000px**, what screen are you actually trying to fit too?

Comment: Are you adding img in `HTML` using `<img>` tag or in `CSS` using `background-image` ?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith It just a concern that I have that there is better way because there is a case like this where it will overflow. I am aware that most desktop screens have close width:height ratio

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui I can go for both ways if there is a good approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use viewport height units.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chats {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.chat {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chats">
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the screen goes bellow ~75px width, the circle becomes an oval.

Comment: Really, a screen thats only 75px wide?

Comment: No more ridiculous from the aspect ratio to cause the issue on the OP :-)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith only because the chats nav is more height and the circle is less width. If I do something like https://jsfiddle.net/Lvqao7gk/ where the chat is more width and the nav is less height it oveflows way easier, so this is better approach for my case